# Query does not return anything PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Edit --> It says that "No database selected", but it is selected :/

The problem is not about query, it returns nothing, I think the problem is about PHP or MySQL, but I'm not sure.

This is my connection class;

```
class DB_functions {
        public $db;
        function __construct() {
            try{
                $this->db = new PDO("mysql:localhost;dbname=xxx;charset=utf8","xxx","xxx");
                echo 'Connected';
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                print $e->getMessage();
                echo "No Connection";
            }
        }
        function __destruct() {}

        public function test(){

            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM User", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($query->rowCount()){
                foreach ($query as $row) {
                    print_r($row);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

And testing code;

```
<?php

require_once('firstcode.php');

$db = new db_functions();

$t = $db->test();

?>
```

It doesn't return anything, and gives that error ; Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object in...

Someone who faced this problem ? I'm using php 5.5

I checked the rowCount() function, but it is not about it, my problem is why query doesn't return anything ? It runs successfully on mysql

Thanks in Advance

Comment: PDO::query returns false on failure http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: The problem is not being failure or false, the problem is that it doesn't return  anything from the table

Comment: It says; No database selected. But as can be seen, db is selected

Comment: @InfoUnfollowers - Variable scope. `$db` inside your `test` function is not defined. You really need to look at a good tutorial so you can figure out how objects work.

Comment: @andrewsi yes you are totally right(I am open any of your suggestion).. It was another problem, was fixed, thank you. But now the thing is that it gives an error like "No database selected" and I still couldn't find any way to solve it..

Comment: @InfoUnfollowers - your DSN looks wrongly formatted - the manual has `mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1`, so you're missing both a host and have a random `localhost`  in yours.

Comment: I am working on hosting, actually i was using standard mysql, but it was out of date, that's why I am recoding all db libraries for PDO, the creditentals are the same as the previous ones. I didn't change dbname or pass.

Comment: I solved the problem by adding this "logical" piece of code; $db->exec("USE "."xxx"); Another Question; Although I already selected the db, why do I have to declare it again ? Thank you for help :)

Comment: @InfoUnfollowers - did you read my previous comment? The DSN in your code in the question is wrong, and it's not actually connecting to the database; so you need to put in your `USE` line. If you had a well-formed DSN then you wouldn't need that.